# Exception AttributeError message when using manage.py in django-nonrel for Google app engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I'm using Python 2.7 and [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel) for running Django projects on Google app engine. I'm using version 1.6 of the Google app engine SDK. I run `python manage.py syncdb` or `python manage.py deploy`. After the command completes I get the following message:

```
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mkstemp'" in <bound method DatastoreFileStub.__del__ of <google.appengine.api.datastore_file_stub.DatastoreFileStub object at 0x8a2422c>> ignored
```

Why do I get this message and is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAE 1.6.0 doesnt work for me too, 1.5.2 does.

Answer (score 2):

It has already been reported.

See [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-non-relational/qEp2UAz20tI/p3RSQezVZIsJ).

Apparently, it doesn't break anything.

As you can see, the [answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-non-relational/qEp2UAz20tI/L6oBV_e-SFoJ) is:

"Dont worry, just ignore it"